# OpenCVSharp: Need help tracking white blobs in moving video file using Bounding Box + Centroids

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision

I'm new to Stack Overflow so I apologize if this question is too broad, off topic, or if I'm about to supply insufficient or unnecessary information, but I really need some assistance! I'm new to computer vision and my task is as follows:

I need to take in a video file (in my particular case we are recording simple human motion patterns such as walking in a straight line, cirle, zig zag, etc... that we will later use to do deep learning through Convolutional Neural Networks) The ultimate goal is for the code to perform background subtraction / foreground detection on the video file, detect & track the white blobs in the foreground mask with a red bounding box (ignoring smaller blobs that should be considered as noise), and most importantly calculate and update the centroids of the bounding box in each frame of the video as the person moves, and output the centroid information at each frame to a text file, rather than the console window. The centroid information will then be used to develop a small deep learning database with Tensorflow so that when we give the program a pattern of unrecognized x,y centroid coordinates, it will compare those coordinates with a pattern of coordinates in the database, and then be able to say "This is Pattern 1 or Patter 2... etc"

This is the code that does the background subtraction on a supplied VIDEO file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus;
using OpenCvSharp.Blob;

namespace OpenCvSharp.Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    class BgSubtractorMOG
    {
        public BgSubtractorMOG()
        {
            //using (CvCapture capture = CvCapture.FromCamera(0)) // for webcam
            //using (IplImage img = cap.QueryFrame())
            using (CvCapture capture = new CvCapture("C:\\Users\\tev\\Documents\\Scenario 1.avi")) // specify your movie file
            using (BackgroundSubtractorMOG mog = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG())
            using (CvWindow windowSrc = new CvWindow("src"))
            using (CvWindow windowDst = new CvWindow("dst"))
            {
            IplImage imgFrame;
            using (Mat imgFg = new Mat(capture.FrameWidth, capture.FrameHeight, MatrixType.U8C1))
                while ((imgFrame = capture.QueryFrame()) != null)
                {
                    mog.Run(new Mat(imgFrame, false), imgFg, 0.01);

                    windowSrc.Image = imgFrame;
                    windowDst.Image = imgFg.ToIplImage();
                    Cv.WaitKey(50);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code that finds the bbox + centroids on IMAGES:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Blob;


namespace WhiteblobDetection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //using (IplImage imgSrc = new IplImage("shapes.png", LoadMode.Color))
            using (IplImage imgSrc = new IplImage("C:\\OpenCvSharp\\TestImage\\mydrawing.png", LoadMode.Color))
            using (IplImage imgBinary = new IplImage(imgSrc.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1))
            using (IplImage imgLabel = new IplImage(imgSrc.Size, CvBlobLib.DepthLabel, 1))
            using (IplImage imgDst = new IplImage(imgSrc.Size, BitDepth.U8, 3))
            {
                Cv.CvtColor(imgSrc, imgBinary, ColorConversion.BgrToGray);
                Cv.Threshold(imgBinary, imgBinary, 200, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);

                using (CvBlobs blobs = new CvBlobs())
                {
                    blobs.Label(imgBinary, imgLabel);

                    int count = 0;
                    foreach (var item in blobs)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} | Centroid:{1} Area:{2}", item.Key, item.Value.Centroid, item.Value.Area);

                        // draw rectangle
                        imgSrc.DrawRect( item.Value.Rect, CvColor.Red);
                        // draw cross at the centroid
                        CvPoint pt1, pt2;
                        int d = 3;
                        pt1.X = (int)item.Value.Centroid.X - d;
                        pt1.Y = (int)item.Value.Centroid.Y;
                        pt2.X = (int)item.Value.Centroid.X + d;
                        pt2.Y = (int)item.Value.Centroid.Y;

                        //imgSrc.DrawLine(item.Value.Centroid, item.Value.Rect.TopLeft, CvColor.Red, 1);
                        imgSrc.DrawLine( pt1, pt2, CvColor.Red, 1);
                        pt1.X = (int)item.Value.Centroid.X;
                        pt1.Y = (int)item.Value.Centroid.Y - d;
                        pt2.X = (int)item.Value.Centroid.X;
                        pt2.Y = (int)item.Value.Centroid.Y + d;
                        imgSrc.DrawLine(pt1, pt2, CvColor.Red, 1);

                    }
                    blobs.RenderBlobs(imgLabel, imgSrc, imgDst);

                }
            }
         }
        }
}
```

I am not looking for someone to write the solution out for me because I wouldn't learn anything that way. (though if you did I'd love you forever! lol). I'm simply looking for ideas or more in depth documentation that I could use to help me learn.

These were two pieces of sample code supplied to me by an advisor. I've modified only what I understand and can find documentation for on the internet, but there isn't much for OpenCVSharp, and being a newbie to computer vision makes it difficult for me to try and port C++ OpenCV code over to OpenCVSharp.

So to sum things up, my task is basically to combine the codes in such a way that the code for finding bbox + centroids on images, works with a video file like in the code for background subtraction. I know that given what I already have, what I'm missing is probably very simple and I just need another set of eyes that can maybe help me spot what's missing.

Comment: If using OpenCVSharp proves difficult, as it's not an officially supported language, I'd suggest to continue on in C++ instead.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Mann I wish I could but this is for a course project and we have to use OpenCVSharp. My advisor simply supplied us with the NuGet wrapper package with all the .dlls